# What would a cluster of N nodes + T topics with P partitions and R replicas "look like"?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have just stated working on kafka and trying to understand the orientation of nodes in the kafka cluster,

considering I have a kafka cluster with 5 nodes and for better understanding, lets say 3 topics each with partition of 2 with a replication factor of 2.

How would this look like in the cluster (when viewed as nodes) ?

Comment: Did you read any books on kafka yet? They are free on Confluent's (the enterprise Kafka company/creators) website

Comment: I am going through kafka docs. and tweaking on my local machine. Also, I will surely go through the e-books provided by confluent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mean 5 nodes, I suppose you have 5 brokers running on node each.

If you have 3 topics with 2 partitions each. Then there are total 6 partitions.

If you have a replication factor of 2, then these 6 partitions become 12.

These partitions are distributed across the brokers.

Each broker can get one or more partitions.

Since you have 5 brokers, it is likely that no two partitions of the same topic might land on the same broker (i.e. same node) for load-balancing purpose.

If a TopicA-Partition-0 is hosted (lead) by Broker1, then Broker1 cannot host the replica of this partition.

This is because if Broker1 goes down, then there should be a replica (or more precisely in-sync replica) from where this partition's data can be consumed or produced to so that its clients will not be effected.

As for partition assignment i.e. which broker gets which topic-partitions, there can be multiple combinations while, I suppose you may manually assign also

Comment: thanks @javaTechnical. Can you also explain a little more on this statement: "When you mean 5 nodes, I suppose you have 5 brokers running on node each."? I mean is this a standard/good practice or a necessary thing to do?

Comment: What I mean by a node is a physical machine or a VM where you can run your Kafka broker processes.